# Function overloading with implicit conversion on const reference and pass by value in C++

Tags: c++, function, overloading, pass-by-reference

Here we have function overloading, where only the one with 'double' type parameters has the option to have implicit conversions, and it is quite obvious why compiler chooses this(double version) version of function

```
double max(double a, double b){
    std::cout<< "double max called" << std::endl;
    return (a>b)?a:b;
}


int& max(int& a, int& b){
   std::cout << "int max called" << std::endl;
    return (a>b)?a:b;
}

int main(){

    char a{6};
    char b{9};


    auto result = max(a,b);

   
    return 0;
}
```

But when we change the second function's parameter to const int&, we make implicit conversions possible. Why is it the case that, both of these version need to make implicit conversion, but the compiler chooses the version with 'const int&' type parameter. Is it because it is closer to type 'char', or there is some kind of rule in compiler?

```
double max(double a, double b){
    std::cout<< "double max called" << std::endl;
    return (a>b)?a:b;
}


const int& max(const int& a, const int& b){
    std::cout << "int max called" << std::endl;
    return (a>b)?a:b;
}

int main(){

    char a{6};
    char b{9};


    auto result = max(a,b);

   
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the compiler to always stick around with easier version which is pass by value

Comment: There's probably a dupe to this effect. According to the [rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences) for ranking implicit conversion sequences, integral promotion (e.g. `char` to `int`) is preferred over a floating-integral conversion (e.g. `char` to `double`)

Comment: @NathanPierson Should not that comment be a answer?